# Using the jquery get function to load a page with a contact form

Tags: jquery

I put together a simplified example of my problem. My HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script style="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a.mylink').click(function(e){
//get the querystring
var href=$(this).attr('href');
var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);
$.get('test_jq.php', querystring, function(data) {
//load the data
$('#mydiv').html(data);
}); 
//stop the link
return false;
});


$('#contact').submit(function() {
alert("you have submitted");
return false;
}); // end submit


});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<a class="mylink" href="test.php?info=A" >A</a>
<a class="mylink" href="test.php?info=B" >B</a>
<a class="mylink" href="test.php?info=C" >C</a>

<div id="mydiv">
Information loaded here.
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the test.jq php file:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' and isset($_GET["info"]) ) 
   {
   $info=$_GET["info"];

   if($info=="A")echo "A";
   elseif($info=="B")
   {
   echo '<form id="contact" method="post" action="email.php" >
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>';
   }
   elseif($info=="C") echo "C";
   }
Here is a working example:

http://www.scratchprogramming.org/test.php
```

Essentially, I am having trouble accessing the handler:

```
$('#contact').submit(function() {
    alert("you have submitted");
    return false;
    }); // end submit
```

when I click the B link and then submit the form ?

Here is a working example:

[Working example](http://www.scratchprogramming.org/test.php)

Thanks..Jillian

Comment: I'm confused. Do you think you could create a jsFiddle?

Comment: So you're dynamically appending an HTML form with the `#contact` id to your page after it has loaded? And then when you click on the element with the `#contact` id, the form is not posting?

Comment: The dynamically appended form posts but the submit handler is not executed. I will try to make a working example in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I used the .on() method  to delegate the submit handler to the document.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#contact', function() {
alert("you have submitted");
return false;
});
```

This solution was provided to me via jquery.org

Comment: Glad you found an answer.  You could also manually bind the handler _after_ you append the form to the DOM (e.g., inside a script tag right after the form).  As I'm sure you realized, the original problem was that you bound the handler to the form before it existed on the page (i.e., on pageload).  So you need to either delegate it to something that already exists at that time (`document`) or bind the handler after you append the form to the DOM (using something like `document.form['myform'].submit = handler`).  BTW, you can go ahead and accept your own answer as correct in 2 days.